# Z-index не перекрывает видео в iframe

Tags: css

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему с помощью z-index, не перекрывается видео с ютуба. Такая проблема наблюдается в safari и хроме (при чем с jsfiddele, в хроме все нормально, а в реальной работе нет. safari - не корректно.). в чем может быть проблема?

Лиса работает правильно.

Для того, чтобы понять в чем проблема, кликните по слову menu в браузере safari.

**[Вот код](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/uSsxP/3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иногда стоит [поискать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074365/youtube-video-embedded-via-iframe-ignoring-z-index) (даже [дважды](http://www.scorchsoft.com/blog/youtube-z-index-embed-iframe-fix/)), перед тем, как повторять вопрос. Добавьте к `url` параметр `wmode` так:

```
&wmode=Opaque
&wmode=transparent
```